# Validation hex and rgba colors using regex in php

Tags: php, regex, laravel, colors

[image: text field]

I am using Laravel and I am trying to validate a color field.
This text box should only allow `HEX`, `rgb`, `rgba`, `hsl` and `hsla` colors using regex pattern.

In my controller I have this pattern but it is not validating my field value. Any string will pass the validation.

```
$this->validate($request, [
    'color' => [
        'required',
        'regex:/(#(?:[0-9a-f]{2}){2,4}|#[0-9a-f]{3}|(?:rgba?|hsla?)\((?:\d+%?(?:deg|rad|grad|turn)?(?:,|\s)+){2,3}[\s\/]*[\d\.]+%?\))/i', // <--- not working
    ],
]);
```

Thanks.

Comment: For testing purposes, please provide a short list of actual inputs so can test my pattern.

Comment: You just have to use `^` and `$` anchors... But a note to your regex: It seems to be matching `rgb(2,2,2,2)` and `rgba(3,3,3,33)` (The first one shouldn't be matching, since it's rgb, not rgba, and the second one shouldn't match any opacity higher than 1)

Comment: @AbdallaArbab Please check my post i have updated it, please check demo link

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You should add anchors (`^` and `$`):

```
'regex:/^(#(?:[0-9a-f]{2}){2,4}|#[0-9a-f]{3}|(?:rgba?|hsla?)\((?:\d+%?(?:deg|rad|grad|turn)?(?:,|\s)+){2,3}[\s\/]*[\d\.]+%?\))$/i',
        ^                                                                                                                     ^
```

To make the regex apply to the whole input instead of just match it.

But please note that your pattern allows input like `rgba(1024, 1023, 0)` which is an invalid color.

---

If you want a more bulletproof regex, use this ([demo](https://regex101.com/r/A2IjNO/4)):

```
^(\#[\da-f]{3}|\#[\da-f]{6}|rgba\(((\d{1,2}|1\d\d|2([0-4]\d|5[0-5]))\s*,\s*){2}((\d{1,2}|1\d\d|2([0-4]\d|5[0-5]))\s*)(,\s*(0\.\d+|1))\)|hsla\(\s*((\d{1,2}|[1-2]\d{2}|3([0-5]\d|60)))\s*,\s*((\d{1,2}|100)\s*%)\s*,\s*((\d{1,2}|100)\s*%)(,\s*(0\.\d+|1))\)|rgb\(((\d{1,2}|1\d\d|2([0-4]\d|5[0-5]))\s*,\s*){2}((\d{1,2}|1\d\d|2([0-4]\d|5[0-5]))\s*)|hsl\(\s*((\d{1,2}|[1-2]\d{2}|3([0-5]\d|60)))\s*,\s*((\d{1,2}|100)\s*%)\s*,\s*((\d{1,2}|100)\s*%)\))$
```

Comment: Upvote. I love bullet-proof regex patterns.  Looks solid to me: http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/7ea50ebe40909e13efbcf53d69d915ca88cbcdd3

Comment: @ThomasAyoub what about MateusA.'s comment on the question?  I don't know enough about the expected syntax.  Is this cooked into your bulletproof pattern?  I think not.  Can you make it even more bullet-proofier?

Comment: @mickmackusa the first one just check the pattern, without checking the rules of rgba/hsla representation. The second does.

Comment: The second pattern _looks_ like it just allows zero or 1 `a` but then doesn't conditionally check the parameters within the trailing parentheses.  Right?  I think this is MatheusA.'s point.  Making this adjustment may be considered overkill and will certainly bloat the pattern, but would allow you to truly call it bulletproof.

Comment: @mickmackusa you're right, I've been a bit lazy there :p

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/143031/discussion-between-thomas-ayoub-and-mickmackusa).

Comment: I wish I could upvote it again.  Well done.  (what a bloated monster of a pattern it is now!  regex is a nasty business.)

Comment: @mickmackusa you can, that's called bounty :p

Comment: No way, Jose!  I'm racing to 3000 so I can re-open some closed questions that I want to answer.

Comment: @ThomasAyoub hooolllaaay. it is working just fine. Thanks.

Comment: Maybe also pass upper case hex color? `^(\#[\da-fA-F]{3}|\#[\da-fA-F]{6}|rgba\(((\d{1,2}|1\d\d|2([0-4]\d|5[0-5]))\s*,\s*){2}((\d{1,2}|1\d\d|2([0-4]\d|5[0-5]))\s*)(,\s*(0\.\d+|1))\)|hsla\(\s*((\d{1,2}|[1-2]\d{2}|3([0-5]\d|60)))\s*,\s*((\d{1,2}|100)\s*%)\s*,\s*((\d{1,2}|100)\s*%)(,\s*(0\.\d+|1))\)|rgb\(((\d{1,2}|1\d\d|2([0-4]\d|5[0-5]))\s*,\s*){2}((\d{1,2}|1\d\d|2([0-4]\d|5[0-5]))\s*)|hsl\(\s*((\d{1,2}|[1-2]\d{2}|3([0-5]\d|60)))\s*,\s*((\d{1,2}|100)\s*%)\s*,\s*((\d{1,2}|100)\s*%)\))$`

Comment: Well you can make the regex case insensitive, it'll cost you less support @AmirMasoud

Comment: By the way, the suggested link to regex 101 had a bug in it, fixed it. It was missing the closing parenthesis for the rgb.https://regex101.com/r/i6qGBT/1

Answer (score 11):

Hope this will help you out. In the below regex, i am also taking care of spaces as well,

> **1.** `#[a-zA-Z0-9]{6}` for matching string like `#090f00`
>
> **2.** `rgb\((?:\s*\d+\s*,){2}\s*[\d]+\)` this will match string like `rgb(10, 10, 20)`
>
> **3.** `rgba\((\s*\d+\s*,){3}[\d\.]+\)` this will match string like `rgba(100,100,100,0.9)`
>
> **4.** `hsl\(\s*\d+\s*(\s*\,\s*\d+\%){2}\)` this will match string like `hsl(10,30%,40%)`
>
> **5.** `hsla\(\s*\d+(\s*,\s*\d+\s*\%){2}\s*\,\s*[\d\.]+\)` this will match string like `hsla(120, 60%, 70%, 0.3)`

**Regex:**

```
#[a-zA-Z0-9]{6}|rgb\((?:\s*\d+\s*,){2}\s*[\d]+\)|rgba\((\s*\d+\s*,){3}[\d\.]+\)|hsl\(\s*\d+\s*(\s*\,\s*\d+\%){2}\)|hsla\(\s*\d+(\s*,\s*\d+\s*\%){2}\s*\,\s*[\d\.]+\)
```

[**Regex demo**](https://regex101.com/r/mjG7Gn/2/)

Comment: @mickmackusa adding it just a minute

Comment: OP uses case insensitive flag to omit `A-Z` and `#fff` is valid.  so `{6}` is too rigid

Comment: Zero or infinity `\s`?  I recommend ` ?`  (space-question mark)  `\s` will allow other whitespace characters as well.

Comment: @mickmackusa There can be case when there are two spaces . Is it possible or not? can you share a hex in which codes length is less or greater than `6`

Comment: `%` doesn't need to be escaped.

Comment: @mickmackusa Just to have safe side i escaped `%`, is there any issue having escaping special characters?

Comment: SO is a resource where people come for the best answers.  We shouldn't be promoting any unnecessary coding practices.  Regex is hard enough to read, let's endeavor to make the pattern as small and clean as possible.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/143029/discussion-between-sahil-gulati-and-mickmackusa).

Answer (score 3):

Since `Laravel 10.33` there is a rule for hex color validation named **[hex_color](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/validation#rule-hex-color)** which makes it very easy and convenient to use.

Example:

```php
$request->validate([
    'color' => ['required', 'hex_color'],
]);
```

Comment: Lovely to have but wish there was support for other types of color codes

Comment: We can do it by making PR 